# Non-lvalue in assignment in class

Tags: c++, class, project, codeblocks

I'm kinda of new at c++, so I need some help. I have to make a function tha books ticket for an event.

```
  void Event::book(int row, int seat, Date date, char *name, char *note)
{
    if(this->date==date && strcmp(this->name,name)==0)
    {
        if(hall.seatsInHall[row-1][seat-1].isFree()==true)
        {
            hall.seatsInHall[row-1][seat-1].isFree()=false; // here it gives me non-lvalue in assignment
            hall.seatsInHall[row-1][seat-1].getNote()=note; // here it gives me non-lvalue in assignment
            hall.seatsInHall[row-1][seat-1].getNote()=note; // here it gives me non-lvalue in assignment
            cout<<"Seat Booked.";
        }
        else cout<<"This seat is already taken or bought.";
    }
    else cout<<"Error.";
}
```

What can I do to not show this mistake?

Comment: i suspect you mean isFree = false, but since you dont show the definition its hard to say. or maybe isFree(false), you gotta show the def of isFree

Comment: isFree() is a bool function in class Seat, which returns true if a seat is free

Comment: If you return the `bool` by value you get a new object that's a copy that's not around long enough to be worth changing the value. Since this is certainly a programming mistake, the compiler slaps the code down. See [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) for a quick rundown of the terminology.

Comment: show the definiton of the class please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because the stuff on the left side of the assignment statements are not lvalues i.e. you cannot assign values to them. The most likely cause is that `getNote()` and `isFree()` are returning-by-value. A function can return an lvalue if (and only if) it returns a reference.

You need to make sure that `isFree()` and `getNote()` return non-const references.

For the two functions having problems in your post, they could look like:

```
bool& isFree()

char*& getNote()
```

While this should fix your errors, in the case of getNote, it's not very pretty. Furthermore, it's not clear which object has ownership of the char* data and that could lead to memory leaks later. A nicer solution would be to change note to `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Your original function signature would then look like:

```
void Event::book(int row, int seat, Date date, char *name, std::string note)
```

And the signature of `getNote()` would be:

```
std::string& getNote()
```

Comment: While you could fix it by returning a reference to a pointer i.e. `char*& getNote()`, a nicer and more robust C++ option would be to use a std::string instead of char* for the note. You benefit from the features and relative security of std::string, and it makes the code more understandable.

Comment: Yes, it's much easier with string. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it working. If this helped you, would you be able to accept my answer?